# How do I properly set up this integral equation?

Tags: vector-analysis, physics

Using the gaussian law I want to determine the field strength of a charged stick on another load.
The base formula for that is 
$$\epsilon_0 \oint {\vec{E} \cdot d \vec{A}} = q$$ 
A second formula for q is:
$$ q = \lambda \cdot h $$ 
$$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\cdot \pi \cdot \epsilon_0} \cdot \frac{q_1}{r^2} \cdot \hat{r}$$ 
In this case we use a cylinder to solve our problem and we only need the lateral surface.
$$A = 2\cdot \pi \cdot d \cdot h$$

**My questions**

1. I have a strong problem with a surface written as vector.
   Assuming we have a situation like in the first picture of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987778/force-of-one-charge-on-another-in-a-3-d-vector-space) where the lateral surface of our cylinder touches the load.
   How would I properly write the surface as vector (how can I determine the direction vector)?
   Usually my approach would be $\vec{r} = (x_2 - x_1)\hat{x} + (y_2 - y_1)\hat{y}$. But as we have a solid here I have problems finding the start and end coordinates.
2. Until now I only solved integrals in the form of $\int f(x) dx$ but now I have an equation like the one above. What would be my "x" here? How would I solve this integral?

As you can imagine this is a task from my electronics class. It's not a homework but it was an example.
Unfortunately we did explicitly **not** pay attention to the integral and we did **not** pay attention to the surface written as vector.
What we did is the following:
$$\epsilon_0 \oint {\vec{E} \cdot d \vec{A}} = q$$
$$\epsilon_0 \cdot |\vec{E}| \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot h \cdot d = q$$ 
Because $\lambda$ is given in this particular task we can do 
$$\epsilon_0 \cdot |\vec{E}| \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot h \cdot d = \lambda \cdot h$$ 
$$|\vec{E}| = \frac{\lambda}{2\cdot \pi \cdot d \cdot \epsilon_0}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to symmetry considerations, $\vec E$ at a given point is always pointing along the line from that point that is perpendicular to the wire. We can use cylindrical coordinates. With $d$ the distance from the wire, we can write $\vec E=E(d)\hat r$. For a surface, the vector $d\vec A$ is always perpendicular to that surface. So in cylindrical coordinates we can write the surface element that is part of the cylinder with radius $r$ as $d\vec A=r d\theta dh \hat r$. Notice that $d\vec A$ and $\vec E$ are parallel (or antiparallel), so $$\vec E\cdot d\vec A=EdA=E d\ d\theta dh$$
Integrating $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $h$ from $0$ to $h$, you get your formula. In conclusion, you get the answer due to the fact that $\vec E$ is always perpendicular to the surface of the cylinder of radius $d$, and is only dependent on the magnitude of $d$.

Comment: Thanks again! I have still one question: How can I find the antiderivative of this? As I mentioned, unfortunately we skipped this part. I know that this is probably absolutely simple but it confuses me anyway. Secondly another probably quite silly question: How would the unit vectors look like?

Comment: Integral over $d\theta$ is $2\pi$, integral over $dh$ is the length of the wire  $L$ (will go to infinity, but will cancel with the charge: $q=\lambda L$)